# load chrome extension on all tabs by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to load a chrome extension on all tabs by default? So that the chrome extension has a permanent overlay? Here is part of my manifest file:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [ "scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "scripts/content.js", "scripts/sidd.js" ],
      "css": [ "styles/sidd.css" ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [ "https://www.google.com/*" ],
      "js": [ "scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "scripts/google.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }, 
    {
      "matches": [ "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zg6c3cyKk30" ],
      "js": [ "scripts/youtube.js" ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: You'll have to insert that overlay as a DOM element into each page. Might make sense to do it only in the active page e.g. by using Page Visibility API in the content script.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any skeleton code that you could post? I'm very, very new to Javascript and am not sure how to use Page Visibility API?